# How to change the css using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a function to change the appearance of some elements in my HTML page  but I am not able to do it.

The problem is that I cannot use a command like

```
document.getElementById('')
```

because I need to make the changes effective when the page is already loaded and I use Django and python. My html page looks like this.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
 .bs-sidebar.affix {
 position: static;
 }
.sideheading{
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fafafa, #e0e0e0);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fafafa, #e0e0e0);
 background-image: linear-gradient(#fafafa, #e0e0e0);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 color: #222;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 border-left: 0 none;
 }

/* First level of nav */
.bs-sidenav {  
 /*margin-bottom: 30px;*/
  padding-top:    10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}

 .bs-sidebar .nav > li > a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: block;
    color: #716b7a;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    }
 .bs-sidebar .nav > li > a:hover,
 .bs-sidebar .nav > li > a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-right: 4px solid #dbd8e0;
}
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active > a,
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active:hover > a,
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active:focus > a {
font-weight: bold;
color: #418cd1;
background-color: #fff;
border-right: 4px solid #418cd1;
}
.xgap{
   margin-top:60px;
  }

.wrap {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }

.progress-radial {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 30px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 2px solid #2f3439;

.progress-radial .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fffde8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

.progress-0 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #2f3439 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), 
               linear-gradient(90deg, #ff6347 50%, #2f3439 50%, #2f3439);
   }
.progress-5 {background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #2f3439 50%, transparent 50%, 
           transparent), linear-gradient(108deg, #ff6347 50%, #2f3439 50%, #2f3439);
 }
</style>

<div class="span6">
  <table class="table table-borderless" style="border:1px solid #C0C0C0;background-
          color:#FBFBFB;">
      <tr><th>First name&emsp;</th><td>:&emsp;{{user.first_name}}</td></tr> --> I use 
                           // Django framework user.first_name is from source file
                           // When the html page is loaded I want to check the td.If td 
                           // has value the profile meter should change from 0% to 10%. 
      <tr><th>Last Name&emsp;</th><td>:&emsp;{{user.last_name}}</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Primary mail&emsp;</th><td>:&emsp;{{ user.email }}</td></tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div class="wrap row">
   <div class="progress-radial progress-{{progress}}" style="margin:10px 0px 20px  
               70px;">-->// here {{progress}}should change according to the td's (i.e) 
                      //initially it is 0% I need a javascript to draw the profile meter.
      <div class="overlay">{{progress}}%</div>--> here {{progress}} should change 
                        // according to the td's (i.e) initially it is 0%  and it 
                        // should change 10%, 20% and so on according to the td's field.
     </div>
</div>

</html>
```

I need a javascript function for changing the profile meter.

Comment: What does the page loading have to do with not being able to use `document.getElementById`?

Comment: Who say you about `getElementById` works before page loads only?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the page to be done loading just use `window.onload`, then you can call `document.getElementById()` inside, which will run when the page is done loading:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // This is only ran after the window is loaded
    document.getElementById('myElementsId').style.[css-property] = [change];
}
```

For example if I wanted to change a color:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myElementsId").style.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: @@Spencer Wieczorek: I want to wrirte a javascript that dynamically changes the progress in  <div class="progress-radial progress-{{progress}}" style="margin:10px 0px 20px 70px;"> with values 5%, 10%,...and so on. Can you help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a progressbar to fill up to a certain value, try the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="progressbar"><div class="progress"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.progressbar { 
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.progressbar .progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  background: #f00;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('progress')[0].style.width = '10%';
```

If you call the above JS line at the bottom of the page (right before `</body>`) it should work like a charm :)

Comment: @@THiCE : Hi,I want a round shaped profile meter. So Please let me know how to fill it when the page is loaded with values inside <td>:&emsp;{{user.first_name}}</td>. Can u tell me the script for it?

Comment: @@THiCE :I want to wrirte a javascript that dynamically changes the progress in  <div class="progress-radial progress-{{progress}}" style="margin:10px 0px 20px 70px;"> with values 5%, 10%,...and so on. Can you help me for this?